# How to change the interface or positions of the home and back buttons after updating a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 tablet?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, user-interface

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 downloaded an update.

Now, the buttons (home, back) on the bar are in the middle. Previously, they were postioned left. It's really uncomfortable. It seems that I received the "mobile user interface" instead of the tablet interface.

How to do I change this?

Comment: On my Nexus 7 (now dead), the position of the home button was also in the middle. Position was the same regardless of orientation (portrait / landscape). I think this is the position for the latest vanilla Android.

Answer (score 0):

Google migrated to using the mobile interface for tablets in android 4.2

You will not be able to change to the previous button arrangement on your stock ROM.

You could root your phone and install a custom ROM such as paranoid android to get back your old button arrangement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can root your phone and install a custom ROM. Also, there is an app called Full!Screen for rooted phones I believe. It let's you remove the buttons and then reposition them. Not sure if it's the right app. Otherwise.. Just search the Play Store for root apps related to buttons